# Is property a container and accessor in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

I have this property in my Class:

```
public string A
{
    set
    {
        A = value;
    }
}
```

It gives me an error whenever I try to assign a value to A. Actually, my IIS Express stops and gives no clue.

I have a feeling that this creates an endless assignment of value to A, it's like a recursion. My questions:

1. What is happening in my code?
2. Is property just an accessor (getter/setter) and not a container when you specify an implementation?
3. When using auto-implemented property, is the property both container and accessor?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have a StackOverflow exception, since you're assigning the property itself in its setter, which results in an endless assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set property variable itself as a container..
you can write like this.

**Scenario 1:**

```
public string A
{
    set;
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
private string _A=String.Empty;
public string A
{
    set{_A=value;}
}
```

let me know if any question.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using an auto implemented property, the compiler generates a container for the value and methods to work with that container (get and set).

When you implement the propriety yourself, like you did, the compiler only generates a set method, that then calls itself, resulting in an endless loop. The correct way to do it would be:

```
private string _a;
public string A
{
    set
    {
        _a = value;
    }
}
```

In this case, the compiler will generate a method to set the value of `_a` , and no recursion occurs.

Comment: So properties are just syntactic sugar? I mean, it translates the getters and setters into methods?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You could do whatever you want in the set method and it will be executed when the property is "assigned" from code. Same for get, except you have to return something to make it compile.